# Connecting to Security with a different password than the rest of Stack

Tags: feature-request, login

I’ll use in this week Security in different computers. This computers aren’t mine so I don’t know if they contain or not a keylogger. Then I whant to log in with a different password than others sites of Stack.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered not logging in this week and acting as an unregistered user? Or creating a new account using a different email?

To answer your question though, you have an ID, whether OpenID, SE etc that is your SE-wide presence. So it will be one password.

What I don't understand is your threat model - why do you need different passwords on SE sites? What are you protecting against?